# Make an excel table from a PDF product catalog - Orange

Tags: excel, pdf, product, catalog, orange

I'm new to this forum and to Orange.
I don't really now Python at this point but am ready to learn.
However, before going further in this environment I would like to know if it can answer my needs !

What I am basically doing is "transforming" PDF product catalogues into Excel files that can be used by another software to create a database for another software.

I have tiles catalogues in PDF just like this one : [image]

and turn it into this type of xls table : https://i.stack.imgur.com/gznYN.jpg

I basically need it to retrieve the article number, the colour, the size (e.g: 20x20). The G/B parts are completed manually after it has been done.

All catalogues are not the same so I sorted out some using pdftotext, RegEx with Notepad++
But I would like to know if this data mining solution could work it out ?

Answer (score 0):

Orange does not support reading PDF files. You will have to use specialized utilities or program it yourself.

Comment: I can actually easily pdftotext it since the pdf document is fully readable (not images but text).